# How to configure an application server in Intellij Idea 13 Ultimate SpringMVC project?

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, application-server

I create new SpringMVC project then choose Run->EditConfiguraions then choose Defaults->TomcatServer->Local on the left, push the button "Configure..." and kinna don't know what to write in the opened dialog. Could you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this window you have to:

1. Configure location of your Tomcat instance (`Application server -> configure -> enter "Tomcat home"`).
2. Then you go to "Deployments" tab and add your artifact (by clicking green cross)

Comment: "Configure location of your Tomcat instance" how to find out where is my tomcat ?

Comment: Where have you extracted downloaded tomcat?

Comment: It came right away with IDE I beleive:

.../idea-IU-133.696/plugins/Tomcat/lib But this path does not fit

Comment: You should download it from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi extract and then select this path

Comment: runs now with error cannot run the program apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/catalina.sh permission denied. How to allow permission?

Comment: What OS do you use? Have you extracted from the same user that you run your IDE?

Comment: Thanks, already solved. Just allowed permission to the file from the command line.

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко great - so now you can accept my answer :)